# datatables adding/removing data to text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add the clicked row of datatables to a textarea and if the same row is clicked again, the data is searched in the textarea and if found removed.
(select/deselect)

If I select one row and the deselect it, it works great. But when I select more than one row and then return to deselect them, only the last selected row is being searched for and removed but not the others.

Any help?

```js
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var str = $("#selectedref").text();
  var ref = table.cell(this, 2).data();
  if (str.indexOf(ref) != -1) {
    var rmvref = ref + "\r\n";
    $("#selectedref").html($("#selectedref").html().replace(rmvref, ""));
  } else {
    var addref = ref + "\r\n";
    var str1 = addref.concat(str);
    $("#selectedref").text(str1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you using the jquery.datatables plugin?

Comment: @Moeri indeed i am

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: Since you're using textarea:

```js
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var str = $("#selectedref").val();
  var ref = table.cell(this, 2).data();
  if (str.indexOf(ref) != -1) {
    var rmvref = ref + "\r\n";
    $("#selectedref").val($("#selectedref").val().replace(rmvref, ""));
  } else {
    var addref = ref + "\r\n";
    var str1 = addref.concat(str);
    $("#selectedref").val(str1);
  }
});
```

---

Try using  < br> to do your linebreaks in your html instead of \r\n.

Your snippet works in this case:

```js
var row1 = "test row 1\r\n";
var row2 = "test row 2\r\n";
var row3 = "test row 3\r\n";

str = row3.concat(row2.concat(row1));

str = str.replace(row2, "");
```

But as soon as you replace str with an element.innerHTML it doesn't work because it doesn't treat newlines the same way.

```js
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var str = $("#selectedref").text();
  var ref = table.cell(this, 2).data();
  var strref = ref + "<br>";
  if (str.indexOf(ref) != -1) {
    $("#selectedref").html($("#selectedref").html().replace(strref, ""));
  } else {
    var str1 = strref.concat(str);
    $("#selectedref").text(strref);
  }
});
```

Edited with working code

Comment: i dont really follow your snippet in the reply. what im trying to do is on row click look if the text is already available in the textarea and if it is to be removed. if not, then add it to the area on a new line.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you were adding the new rows to a var instead of an elements html then your code will work. But in your case you should use < br> tags instead of \r\n and then your replace would work.

Comment: thank you explaining. it makes sense now. but the edited code above doest "add" the new line. it replaces everything. also the <br> is shown. im using <textarea> to show the lines.

Comment: Edited my answer since I had no idea you were using textarea!

Comment: they edited version still replaces the whole "value" of <textarea> and doesnt add the new clicked row. the new row is replacing previous value :/

Comment: Oops replaced the first .text() with .val()

Comment: removing the line if available is not working :/ adding a new line is working great.

Answer (score 0):

at last i have figured it out!

```js
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var str = $("#selectedref").text();
  var ref = table.cell(this, 2).data();
  if (str.indexOf(ref) != -1) {
    var rmvref = ref + "\r\n";
    $("#selectedref").text($("#selectedref").text().replace(rmvref, ""));
  } else {
    var addref = ref + "\r\n";
    var str1 = addref.concat(str);
    $("#selectedref").text(str1);
  }
});
```